# For some reason, cant get the data from an api to render on the screen using axios in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, api

[image]So Ive been trying for hours to get my api data to render on a screen in reactjs. Ive tried adjusting the map method and playing around with the code but it keeps giving me errors

It doesnt render the info that I am seeing in my console

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from "axios"

const user_key="cf7a5f91a3331dc1409df6bb967b9689103967f70b5b0f80fef391a4df5a1039"


class App extends Component {

  state = {
    searching: []
  }



  getInfo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   const info = e.target.elements.search.value;
   axios.get(`https://api.mattermark.com/search?key=${user_key}&term=${info}`)
   .then((res) => {
     console.log(res.data);
     this.setState({ searching: res.data})

   })
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const entered = e.target.value;
    console.log(entered);
  }



  render() {
    console.log(this.state.searching)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
        </header>
        <form onSubmit={this.getInfo}> 
          <input name="search" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.searching.map((company)=> {
          return(
            <div>
             {company}
            </div>
          )

        })}
         {this.state.searching ? <p>Data: {this.state.searching}</p> : "Please type something! "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My actual result is showing errors 
Expected result is to map the various company names from the key "object_name"

PLease see pictures for more info. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You are trying to render `company` object, objects can't be rendered, try to render one of its properties. Also hide your user_key from the snippet ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
{this.state.searching.map((company)=> {
      return(
        <div>
         Type:{company.object_type}
         Name:{company.object_name}
        </div>
      )

    })}
```

You can't render an object.

**UPD:** you can use another component for render info about the company and pass data in your mapping, I would do something like this.

```
const CompanyInfo = ({data}) => (
          <div>
              <p>{data.object_type}</p>
              <p>{data.object_type}</p>
          </div>
)
```

And then:

```
{this.state.searching.map((company)=> {
      return(
        <CompanyInfo data={company} />
      )
    })}
```